# NullPointerException in Multithreaded Java code

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to run the program, but it throws an exception, which I am not able to fix.

```
public class Multithread extends Thread {

    static int  [][]array1;
    static int  [][]array2;
    static int  [][]array3;

    static final int i=10;
    static final int j=10;
    static final int k=10;

    volatile int start;
    volatile int end;

    Multithread(int start,int end){
        this.start=start;
        this.end=end;
    }

    private static void multiplication() {   
        int processors=Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
        int threadcount=processors>=i ? i:processors;
        Thread [] t=new Thread[threadcount];

        int [] idx= new int[threadcount+1];

        for(int a=0;a<=threadcount;a++){
            idx[a]=(a*i)/threadcount;
            //System.out.println("idx:"+idx[a]);
        }

        for(int a=0;a<threadcount;a++){
            t[a]=new Multithread(idx[a],idx[a+1]);
            //thread 1=start 0 end 9, thread 2 = 9 end =19
            t[a].start();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int a = 0; a < i; a++) 
            for(int b = 0; b < j; b++) 

                array1[a][b]= (int)(Math.random()*10);

        for(int a=0;a<j;a++)
            for(int b=0;b<k;b++)
                array2[a][b]= (int)(Math.random()*10);

        long starttime=System.nanoTime();
        multiplication();
        long endtime=System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("Total time taken is "+((endtime-starttime)/1000));
    }

     public void run(){
         for(int a=start;a<end;a++){
            for(int b=0;b<k;b++){
                for(int c=0;c<j;c++){
                     array3[a][b]=(array3[a][b]+(array1[a][c]*array2[c][b]));
                 }
             }
         }
     }
}
```

This code will give the execution time for the matrix in parallel programming. It gives me `NullPointerException`. I can't fix that. it gives the exception for the array1[a][b]. I tried resolving it, but could not.

Answer (score 0):

You don't properly initialize your variables. Just initialize your 2d array to something, so you can later just pass reference.

```
array1 = blah blah //this is right 
array1[a][b] //you are creating it like this everytime which is wrong.
```